# Forward to other domain with CNAME

Tags: dns, godaddy

In my GoDaddy DNS manager, I made some A Record that points to *.mirror for my domain

[image]

Now when I access URL `123.mirror.mydomain.com` from the browser I can see that my app is loaded, and its all OK.

My problem now is when doing a CNAME `point to` the URL above on `another domain` like this:

[image]

Accessing 123.otherdomain.com which I expect to "forward to" 123.mirror.mydomain.com I only get this 404 error:

[image]

The IP `173.194.71.121` is actually ghs.googlehosted.com

What I am missing here? Why `123.otherdomain.com` which points to `123.mirror.mydomain.com` cannot open that page and I think google is handing the web page request?

Answer (score 3):

This is rather simple. You cannot just redirect traffic anyway you want with DNS. That is not what it does. In this case, it appears that you only have one half of the equation.

What you are missing is that the HTTP request packet header has a domain address within it that the web server compares to it's list on known sites. You are packaging request packets with 123.mirror.mydomain.com in the header and your web server does not have a matching site for this address. You would have to create the 123.mirror.mydomain.com site on your web server and potentially redirect it to where you want it to go if that is what you want to do- otherwise, that is where you would deploy the site you intend.

Comment: Yes, I have my GAE app to handle *.mirror.mydomain.com like this: 123.mirror.mydomain.com